# "sfcb" service status is shown as "active(exited)"

Tags: services

I installed sfcb on Ubuntu 18.04 system. It got installed without any errors. I can start and stop the service without any errors.

However When I check status of the sfcb service, as given below, it is shown as "**active(exited)**"

```
*zebra@zebra-OptiPlex-3040:~$ systemctl status sfcb
● sfcb.service - LSB: Start sfcb
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sfcb; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2021-06-10 18:07:56 +0530; 1h 24min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 20481 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/sfcb stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20499 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/sfcb start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
ජූනි 10 18:07:56 zebra-OptiPlex-3040 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start sfcb...
ජූනි 10 18:07:56 zebra-OptiPlex-3040 sfcb[20499]:  * Starting the small footprint CIM broker (SFCB)
ජූනි 10 18:07:56 zebra-OptiPlex-3040 sfcb[20507]: --- sfcbd V1.4.9 started - 20506
ජූනි 10 18:07:56 zebra-OptiPlex-3040 sfcb[20507]: --- invalid control statement:
ජූනි 10 18:07:56 zebra-OptiPlex-3040 sfcb[20499]:    ...done.
ජූනි 10 18:07:56 zebra-OptiPlex-3040 sfcb[20507]: 8: httpsProcs:     8
ජූනි 10 18:07:56 zebra-OptiPlex-3040 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start sfcb.
ජූනි 10 18:07:56 zebra-OptiPlex-3040 sfcb[20507]:*
```

I am very new to Linux and I am clueless on how to fix this.
Please help me to resolve this issue? Did anyone else observe this issue?

Comment: Did you try the service or just check the status?

Comment: Thanks @SimpliFixed for looking into this. Yes I just checked status. 
I tried "ps -e | grep sfcb" and it does not return anything.
Is there another way to check whether the SFCB is running properly?

Comment: do a service sfcb stop and then check the status, if it changed it was running, if not, it was not, then try the exec start command listed, one thing that I wonder about in your setup is in the output listed as invalid control statement, this may be preventing it from starting, but try stopping it first, check status, if no change then try /etc/init.d/sfcb start instead of service/systemctl

Comment: @SimpliFixed Thank you very much for your support. Got it fixed.
Yes the issue was with that reported invalid control statement. SFCB config file in "/etc/sfcb/sfcb.cfg". Removed the mentioned line having the issue. "https Procs:   8".
And now SFCB runs as expected and status is shown as "active (running)".